# Unable to infer schema for CSV in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using databricks and trying to read in a csv file like this:

```
df = (spark.read      
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv(path_to_my_file)
)
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
AnalysisException: 'Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.;'
```

I've checked that my file is not empty, and I've also tried to specify schema myself like this:

```
schema = "datetime timestamp, id STRING, zone_id STRING, name INT, time INT, a INT"
df = (spark.read      
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(schema)
  .csv(path_to_my_file)
)
```

But when try to see it using display(df), it just gives me this below, I'm totally lost and don't know what to do.

`df.show() and df.printSchema()` gives the following:
[image]

[image]

It looks like that data are not being read into the dataframe.

error snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you give a sample record from CSV.  What is the output of `df.show()` in manually specifying a schema.

Comment: If you look at the logs, it should describe what the error was. Most likely it can't infer the schema due to parsing issues or incompatible types.

Comment: can you run `df.printSchema()`

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol I've updated the post to include more info, thanks for the help.

Comment: To infer the schema you need to have data in the file. Just check whether the file contains only headers or it has data also?

Comment: @dassum, yes I've checked that my file has data in it.

Comment: can you post the first few lines of your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, this is an incomplete answer as there isn't enough information about what your file looks like to understand why the `inferSchema` did not work.  I've placed this response as an answer as it is too long as a comment.

Saying this, for programmatically specifying a schema, you would need to specify the schema using `StructType()`.

Using your example of 
`datetime timestamp, id STRING, zone_id STRING, name INT, time INT, mod_a INT"`

it would look something like this:

```
# Import data types
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType(
   [StructField('datetime', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('zone_id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('name', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('time', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('mod_a', IntegerType(), True)
   ]
  )
```

Note, how the `df.printSchema()` had specified that all of the columns were datatype string.

Answer (score 5):

I discovered that the problem was caused by the filename.

Perhaps databrick is unable to read filename schemas that begin with '_'. (underscore).

I had the same problem, and when I uploaded the file without the first letter (ie, underscore), I was able to process it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the abfss://@.**blob**.core.windows.net/ to abfss://@.**dfs**.core.windows.net/

it worked.